# Notification isn't silent even though i used notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);

Tags: android, notifications

somehow my notification still makes a sound. What did i do do wrong?

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // For foreground service
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        // Creating channel for notification
        String id = BackroundService.class.getSimpleName();
        String name = BackroundService.class.getSimpleName();
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(id,
                name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager service = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        service.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);

        // Foreground notification
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, id)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("KSL is protecting you!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker("Ticker text")
                .build();

        startForeground(9, notification);
    }
```

I used the `notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);` Method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide your channel id to your notification.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, id)
            .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("KSL is protecting you!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTicker("Ticker text")
            .setChannelId(channelId)
            .build();
```

**Edit**

Make sure you uninstall and reinstall your app for changes to take effect.

**Edit 2**

```
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(id,
            name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```

Android system sets notification importance to **NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH** (this plays sound by default) even if you provide importance to **NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT** (this doesn't play sound by default). I don't know why this happnes but for solution to your problem I will recommend to change the important to **NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW**.

Comment: I used the ID 'id' as set in <<NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(id,
                name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);>>

Comment: @SlartiDev make sure you uninstall and reinstall your app for changes to take effect.

Comment: I've reinstalled it. There is still a sound.

Comment: I edited my answer please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Worked! Thanks allot.